# Compare two objects by id

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes in C# - they contain the same properties but are from different APIs.

I have an incoming request which contains new CarAgreements and then an API which returns current CarAgreements.  Both CarAgreements contain AgreementId and AgreementDate - however they are not the same object in order to do a .Equals on.

If the incoming request AgreementId does not match the current agreement id then on the request I need to set the AgreementDate to Todays Date

This is how I have coded this at the minute - is there a better approach to this:

```
    List<CarAgreement> requestedCarAgreements = request.CarAgreements;
    List<AnotherAPI.Models.CarAgreement> currentCarAgreements = GetCurrentCarAgreements();
    
    if(currentCarAgreements != null)
    {
      foreach(var currentCarAgreement in currentCarAgreements)
      {
         foreach(var requestedCarAgreement in requestedCarAgreements)
         {
            if(currentCarAgreement.AgreementId != requestedCarAgreement.AgreementId)
            {
               requestedCarAgreement.AgreementDate = DateTime.Now
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of `AgreementId`? You can use `Guid.Equality` to compare `Guid`.

Comment: @Chyuae = sorry - should have specified - it is a string (like "123456789")

Comment: Well for comparing two strings you can use `String.Compare` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Except` and an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation to find requested agreements that are not present in current agreements.

Something like this should work:

```cs
public class Agreement
{
    public string AgreementId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AgreementDate { get; set; }
}

public class AgreementService
{
    private class AgreementComparer: IEqualityComparer<Agreement>
    {
        public bool Equals(Agreement x, Agreement y) => y != null && x != null && x.AgreementId == y.AgreementId;
        public int GetHashCode(Agreement obj) => obj.AgreementId.GetHashCode();
    }

    public void UpdateAgreements(List<Agreement> agreements)
    {
        var current = GetCurrentAgreements();
        foreach (var agreement in agreements.Except(current, new AgreementComparer()))
        {
            agreement.AgreementDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private List<Agreement> GetCurrentAgreements() => new List<Agreement>();
}
```

Comment: and this should work even though both of the Agreements are actually different objects?

Comment: I'm only comparing `AgreementId`s not whether they're different objects in memory

Comment: I will have to transform both CarAgreement  classes to the class you defined as Agreement though right

Comment: Just replace the names. I used Agreement for brevity.

Comment: but how can I have an IEqualityComparer<CarAgreement> when one CarAgreement class is not the same class as the other CarAgreement class

Comment: Use your own CarAgreement class, not mine. I just put it there as a sample to show how it's implemented. Not all code you see here on StackOverflow is made for copy-and-paste.

Comment: I realize that - my point is one CarAgreement class comes from API A - the other CarAgreement class comes from API B - how can I write an IEqualityComparer on these - unless you mean write my own intermediate CarAgreement class - that each A and B are transformed too before running the compare?

Comment: Implement `IEquatable<ApiCarAgreement>` in your `CarAgreement` class

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine.  You could use Linq :

```
            if(currentCarAgreements != null)
            {
                List<CarAgreement> wrongDates = currentCarAgreements
                  .SelectMany(x => requestedCarAgreements
                      .Where(y => (x.AgreementId != y.AgreementId))
                      .Select(z => z))
                  .ToList();  
                foreach(CarAgreement wrongDate in wrongDates)
                {
                    wrongDate.AgreementDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I get x does not exist in current context with this bit of linq?

Comment: Try foreach(CarAgreement wrongDate in wrongDates.Where(x => x != null))

Comment: I mean on the projection in the Where Clause

Comment: Teh make is var instead of CarAgreement

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether two objects of different types are equal by their values with this:

```
public static bool CheckObjectsEquality(object test1, object test2)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties1 = test1.GetType().GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo[] properties2 = test2.GetType().GetProperties();

    if (properties1.Length != properties2.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < properties1.Length; i++)
    {

        var prop1Value = properties1[i].GetValue(test1);
        var prop2Value = properties2[i].GetValue(test2);

        if (!prop1Value.Equals(prop2Value))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have made a LINQ request :

```cs
var currentIds = currentCarAgreements.Select(a => a.AgreementId).ToHashSet();
requestedCarAgreements.Where(r => currentIds.Contains(r.AgreementId))
    .ToList().ForEach(r => r.AgreementDate = DateTime.Now);
```

Maybe the `HashSet` is overkill, but if you have a lot of current agreement, this improve a lot the performance.